# VueJS calling a method from within a local function, scoping issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope, this, quasar

I have a component set up to communicate with a serial device via a plug-in, once the data is received it has a success function where it is processed and from there i want it to execute a function, in context my problem is that the **this** for the showNotify function stops working once its within the **function success(){ ... }**, the function in nestled inside **watch:** and **showNotify** defined in the **methods:**.
I've tried with call() and bind() but im pretty sure i messed up the syntax as i have no experience with those tools.

```
// watch is on the look for a boolean than then triggers the serial write and readcallback, 
// those work just fine and as intended, problem arises when reaching the code inside the function

watch: {
       ...
         ...
           function success(){
              this.showNotify();
           }
         ...
       ...
},
methods: {
       showNotify {
            this.$q.notify({
            position: 'bottom-left',
            badgeStyle: 'background-color: transparent; box-shadow: none' ,
            badgeTextColor: 'transparent',
            message: 'Device Connected',
            type: 'primary',
            color: 'red-3',
            })
        }
}
```

When i remove the **function(){}** and just leave the **this.showNotify()** the notification appears, but i need it to execute from within the function. Any idea of a workaround for this or proper use of call() or bind() for vueJS?

Thanks!

Comment: For traditional functions (those created with the `function` keyword), the value of `this` is set when the function is called, according to a variety of rules.

Comment: `walrusKing` you should `bind` it correctly, Or use `arrow function`

Comment: An arrow function did the trick! Thanks!